# Delete Lync 2013 Meeting Scheduled via UCWA for expired application

Tags: lync, ucwa

I'm trying to delete a scheduled online meeting created via UCWA, but I couldn't.

I'm using  MS Lync UCWA SDK, as following:

```
    MeetingManager.DeleteMeeting({
        MeetingLink: '/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/1032602521/onlineMeetings/myOnlineMeetings/5D15G7BW',
        onDeleteMeeting: function (data) {
            console.warn(data);
        }
    });


    function DeleteMeeting(options)
    {
        options = $.extend({
            MeetingLink: '',
            onDeleteMeeting: null
        }, options);

        ucwa.Transport.clientRequest({
            url: options.MeetingLink,
            type: "delete",
            callback: function (data) {
                if (options.onDeleteMeeting !== null) options.onDeleteMeeting(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

and what I'm getting is:

responseText: "{"code":"NotFound","subcode":"ApplicationNotFound","message":"An error occurred. Please retry. If the problem persists, contact your support team."}"

**So, how can I delete a Lync 2013 online Meeting scheduled via UCWA for expired UCWA application?**

Answer (score 0):

If you create another UCWA application, you can make a series of requests to get the collection of online meetings associated with that user as follows:

- GET on /onlineMeetings
- GET on /onlineMeetings/myOnlineMeetings
- DELETE on the desired meeting via _links.self.href

If you are wondering how to track a meeting, I would suggest using the onlineMeetingId (*in the above case it is 5D15G7BW*) because as you have learned Urls expire with the application, but onlineMeetingId should be valid between application runs (*assuming the meeting wasn't created with an expirationTime*).

Relevant Fiddler trace: [DELETE myOnlineMeeting.saz](https://db.tt/v7jyB22n)